# Using jax.clear_caches() in JAX

Tags: machine-learning, caching, memory-leaks, jax

I am trying to train a neural network with JAX on GPUs/GPU, but after so many epochs the programme runs out of memory. Using `jax.profiler.save_device_memory_profile` after each epoch I noticed that the memory would increase by the same amount after each epoch. I suspect that since I use vmap and pmap for non-trivial functions with differently sized inputs, perhaps the functions are being recompiled per epoch.

The setup consists of a training function which intakes the number of epochs to train and then I train within a `for` loop, with something looking like this:

```
for i in range(number_of_epochs):
   self._trainer.train(1)
```

I want to use JAX's `jax.clear_cashes()` to see if indeed an accumulation of cashed functions could be resulting to this memory leak. To do so, I write:

```
for i in range(number_of_epochs):
   self._trainer.train(1)
   jax.clear_cashes()
```

In doing so, after the first epoch I get the error:

```
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
```

I'm not yet fully confident in understanding how to use `jax.clear_cashes()`. Any help?

**Edit:**
Perhaps it may be hard to provide a solution to the above given the information I provided, but what would certainly help me debug this problem is if there was a way to find out how many cached functions there are after each epoch - how could I do that?

Comment: to check cache size for each function you can use func_name._cache_size()

Comment: If I try do this, I get the error: AttributeError: `'JittedFunc' object has no attribute '_cache_size'`

Answer (score 1):

We need a minimal working example of your full code to understand what is happening exactly.

The questions hints for a solution about jax caches, but the problem might be somewhere else.

My first thought goes to an array that is growing in size and that resides on the computing device.
For example, the loss being appended to a list of losses, or any other statistics that takes a relevant portion of memory.
If the program is running at the edge of memory capacity even a small array might be sufficient to force the program OOM.